# how to host asp webapp in Linux?

Tags: linux, asp

I tried apache asp but it doesn't work well. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

ASP is a bit out-of-date and afaik there are no alternatives. Maybe you should move to ASP.NET (http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) or to the common stuff like PHP,Python,Ruby,etc. (even if they are sometimes not so "feature-rich") If you are bound to the ASP stuff you could also tell us what doesn't work well with Apache::ASP :)

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) provides details of 2 solutions. But [machine translation](http://asp2php.naken.cc/) works surprisingly well.

Is there a better solution - yes, don't write code using products with a predefined redundancy.